# Pods are deleted regularly

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster, created and managed from stackpoint.io.

The cluster is made of 1 master and 2 nodes, all running on coreOs.

I created 5 deployments with 1 replicas each and 5 services pointing to these deployments.

5 pods are created from these deployments.

My problem is : **between 24 to 36 hours after the pods are created, they are automatically deleted and recreated**.

because these different apps rely on each other to work, it takes about 3-5 minutes of downtime before everything works correctly again.

I assume there is some configuration I don't know about that control this behavior.

I tested using containers with *latest* tag as well as not latest. I tested changing the pullStrategie from *Always* to *IfNotPresent*. I tested using a ubuntu based cluster instead of CoreOs. In every configuration the pods are deleted and recreated

Comment: Why don't you check the logs out? You can check the last state of your pod or you can view the logs of you previous pod. Moreover, CoreOS update-strategy  might be the reason. Actually, you can do a lot of things to locale the problem. How anybody could help you without this?

Comment: `kubectl describe pod $the_pod` and look at the `Termination Reason`, as I'd bet it's 139 `OOMKilled`, or similar. Unless you mean that on Monday you `kubectl get pod alpha` and on Tuesday you `kubectl get pod alpha` and that _specific_ pod is no longer there, instead replaced by `beta`. Do you mean _restarted_ or do you mean _deleted_?

Comment: I mean deleted, I've got nothing about the old pod, the restart count is still 0 and the pod age is reset to 0

Comment: @BlueMagma, Can you share the logs from previous pods before termination, like kubectl logs pod --previous=true?

Comment: @mk_sta, I can't because there is no previous, the pod is delete, not restarted, the restarts count is 0

Comment: Maybe 'kubectl get events' could reveal something

Comment: @Ryan : thank you for the advice, I ran it and got : "no resources found"

Comment: Maybe try `kubectl get events --all-namespaces`

Comment: I still get no resources with --all-namespaces